# Como utilizar Jquery com Vue.js?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Durante a implementação do Vue.js com sematic-ui,

tenho o seguinte Jquery para abrir o modal:

```javascript
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

como fazer essa integração no Vue?

Comment: Nessa aula do Vedovelli ensina como abrir um modal jquery. http://www.vedcasts.com.br/series/vuejs/aula19

Comment: Esse link aí, sempre que clica, volta para a mesma página. @MarcelloRGonçalves

Answer (score 7):

Com `v-el` é possível "marcar" os elementos html para serem usados dentro de componentes.
Também é possível usar diretivas customizadas para fazer essas manipulações.

```html
<span v-el:msg>hello</span>
<span v-el:other-msg>world</span>
```

```javascript
this.$els.msg.textContent // -> "hello"
this.$els.otherMsg.textContent // -> "world"
```

---

Referências:

http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el
http://vuejs.org/examples/select2.html

Answer (score 5):

Ao fazer o include de jQuery via tag script o objeto jQuery estará automaticamente atrelado ao objeto window, podendo então ser utilizado normalmente dentro de um componente Vue. Basta pegar uma referência ao markup do modal utilizando v-el.

Ex.:

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" v-el:modal>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

E no seu componente:

```js
{
  methods: {
    metodoAssociadoAoCliqueUsuario () {
      jQuery(this.$els.modal).modal('show')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa resposta é para aqueles que caíram aqui pelo Google ou busca no SO mesmo.

Não é indicado usar Jquery com Vue, pois ambos manipulam o DOM (no Vue temos o virtual DOM e essa é somente a resposta simples). Sempre que precisar usar algo que usa o jquery (como o materialize, apesar da versão a partir do 1.0 não utlizar mais,  ou bootstrap) procure se não existe algum componente pronto para Vue. Hoje em dia (2019), é possível chamar o jquery normalmente num 'method' ou 'computed' do Vue, e executá-lo como no exemplo do Fabio Vedovelli.

```
{
    methods: {
        metodoaAssocioadoAoClique: function() {
            $('#id_do_componente').modal('show');
        }
}
```

Uma coisa importante a se lembrar é, que caso tenha necessidade de chamar um outra função dentro  da chamada jquery, deve inicializar o 'this' antes, como se segue:

```
{
    methods: {
        outraFuncao: function() {
            return alert("teste")
        }
        metodoaAssocioadoAoClique: function() {
            var self = this;
            $('#id_do_componente').modal({
                //como opção do componente, tenho que chamar outra função
                self.outraFuncao();
            });
        }
}
```

Não sou ainda um profundo conhecedor, pois ainda estou conhecendo e experimentado o Vue (e também sou novo em programação ainda).

Referências:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

DOM e o Virtual DOM do Vue

https://medium.com/js-dojo/whats-the-deal-with-vue-s-virtual-dom-3ed4fc0dbb20

Esse é um Vue contra Jquery (mais propaganda para o Vue do que uma análise)

https://www.educba.com/vue-js-vs-jquery/